# installing firebase with expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am using expo cli to build a react native mobile application, and I am trying to install firebase to add chat and notifications features, and I am getting this error when applying this command

expo install firebase

Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

I am using expo cli to build a react native mobile application, and I am trying to install firebase to add chat and notifications features, and I am getting this error when applying this command

expo install firebase

Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

```
        [4/5] ⠠ grpc
error C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\grpc: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\grpc
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.14.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@14.15.1 | win32 | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.24.2 and node@14.15.1 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@14.15.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@14.15.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.0 found at "C:\Python39\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.8.30717.126) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - "Visual Studio C++ core features" missing
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1321) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - "Visual Studio C++ core features" missing
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Tech One\\Desktop\\FSW\\FinalProject\\latest\\backend\\fueldelivery_react\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\Tech One\\Desktop\\FSW\\FinalProject\\latest\\backend\\fueldelivery_react\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Tech One\\Desktop\\FSW\\FinalProject\\latest\\backend\\fueldelivery_react\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Tech One\\Desktop\\FSW\\FinalProject\\latest\\backend\\fueldelivery_react\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Tech One\Desktop\FSW\FinalProject\latest\backend\fueldelivery_react\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83



yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\Tech One\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Tech One\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\Tech One\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at YarnPackageManager._runAsync (C:\Users\Tech One\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:288:31)
    at YarnPackageManager.addAsync (C:\Users\Tech One\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:241:16)
    at installAsync (C:\Users\Tech One\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\install.ts:117:3)
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tech One\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:302:7)
```

Comment: Were you by any chance able to figure this out? Im running into the same issue.

Comment: no not yet :( I am stuck and I can't continue working on the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `npm install @mapbox/node-pre-gyp --save`, then uninstall the firebase you tried to install, using `npm uninstall firebase`, now use `npm install firebase`.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade firebase      `6.3.4` a `8.2.0` con `npm install firebase`